# Why isn't the last Bootstrap class taking effect?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `article` tag that I am conditionally applying a css class.  Here is my div with my `ng-class` logic in it.

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'col-sm-9': showRightNav === false }" id="tithSlip6">
```

If my right nav doesn't show, then I want to increase the size of the `article`.  It evaluates like it should, but the `css` doesn't take effect.  Here is the `html` copied out of my dev tools:

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-9" ng-class="{ 'col-sm-9': showRightNav === false}" id="tithSlip6"></article>
```

As shown, the class has been added, but the styles stay the same on the page.  What could be a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS styles which will be selected are not dependent on the order of the class names in the `class` attribute in the HTML, but rather the order of rules in the CSS (and their specificity).

The specificity of classes `col-sm-6` and `col-sm-9` are the same and the order of the classes is (probably) not correct in the Bootstrap CSS file you are using. Hence, you are seeing `col-sm-6` take effect even when both classes are applied on the element.

The more idiomatic way to do it (which will also fix the problem) would be to use only one of the two classes on the element, conditioned on `showRightNav`:

```
<article class="col-xs-12" 
         ng-class="{ 
           'col-sm-9': !showRightNav, 
           'col-sm-6': showRightNav 
           }" 
         id="tithSlip6">
```